# Allow 32-bit application use more than 4GB of ram under FreeBSD

Tags: c++, clang, freebsd, clang++

I'm currently developing a game under FreeBSD. I am compiling it using `clang` as a 32bit binary and running it under a 64bit system (I have 32GB of RAM under this system), but I need from it to use more than 4GB of RAM, since it is using only 4GB.
Even if I run multiple instances of the game, it can't access more than 4GB of RAM.

Also, I've tried to compile it under 64-bit system, but it has a strange behaviour. I get a lot of bugs.

I know that Visual Studio on Windows there is an option `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE`, or something like that which makes 32bit application able to use more RAM, or I am wrong?
Are there any flags which I can specify (like the Windows one) to make my binary able to use more RAM? I've read something about `mcmodel=large` (or `medium`), but I am not sure that this is what I'm looking for.
How about cross-compiling? Does anyone knows where I can find some good information about it?
Thank you.

Comment: "Also, I've tried to compile it under 64-bit system, but it has a strange behaviour. I get a lot of bugs." -- You'll want to fix those bugs then. If you have concrete problems that you are unable to solve by yourself, that could make for a good question. That applies to Windows as well: `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE` won't let your application address more than 4GB either.

Comment: Look into memory mapped files.

Answer (score 4):

You can only address 4GiB with a 32 bit integer. 2^32 = 4294967296 = 4 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024

There's no way to have more than 4GiB of address space in a 32 bit executable. That's a mathematical limitation. Admittedly you can use swapping and Physical Address Extensions to deal with more than 4GiB of data in a process, but at any given time you can not address more than 4GiB.

Comment: PAE is only relevant for kernel mode. The user mode equivalent would be something like `mmap`. Either way, the only way to address more than 2^32 bytes is to swap (or "bank") parts of your address space.

Comment: @Rhymoid: Indeed PAE is only relevent for kernel mode, but I wanted to keep the answer and general as possible. 32 bit means 4 GiB of address space and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

To use more than 4GB of RAM, you need 64 bit version of FreeBSD.  This basically means "amd64" instead of "i386" architecture.  You can run 32 bit binaries under 64 bit system, and this will make it possible for the multiple instances to use more than 4GB of RAM; obviously a single one won't be able to address more than that.

Comment: As I specified, I run it under a dedicated server with 32GB of RAM and FreeBSD x64, using 30 instances of it, but I always have over 26GB of free RAM. Also, I have a mysql server on it which uses RAM. It should use more RAM I think.

Comment: It should.  Can you paste the actual stats?